# R package and S4 objects: "unable to find an inherited method" error

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

I'm writing my first R package and am struggling a little with inheritance and method definitions in S4. I'm using standard package organization (`usethis::create_package()`)

I've defined this class in file `R/set-class.R`:

```
#' @title The Set class
#' @slot ris A 2-column character dataframe 
#' @slot tfs A character vector of TF names
#' @import dplyr
#' @export
setClass(
  "set",
  slots = list(
    ris = "data.frame",
    tfs = "character"
  )
)
#' @title Constructor function of a set object.
#' @description Constructor function of a set object.
#' @param ris A 2-column character dataframe of TF-gene interactions.
#' @param tfs A character vector of TF names.
#' @return A `set` object.
#' @export
set <-  function(ris, tfs) {
  new("set", ris = ris, tfs = tfs)
}
```

Then I defined this method in file `R/set-methods.R`:

```
#' @name get_tfs
#' @aliases get_tf,set-method
#' @param x A `set` object
#' @docType methods
#' @rdname set-methods
#' @return A character vector
setGeneric("get_tfs",
           valueClass = "character",
           function(x){
             standardGeneric("get_tfs")
           }
)
setMethod(
  "get_tfs",
  signature(x = "set"),
  function(x) {
    x@tfs
  }
)
```

Now I build a "set" object and try to use the method:

```
> test <- set(ris, tfs)
> is(test)
[1] "set"
> get_tfs(test)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘get_tfs’ for signature ‘"set"’
```

Here is the content of `NAMESPACE`:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(cset)
export(get_tfs)
export(pset)
export(set)
export(summarize)
exportClasses(cset)
exportClasses(pset)
exportClasses(set)
```

Complete code is available [here](https://github.com/rioualen/NetworkEval)

Comment: So, there's some information that we'd need to diagnose this, but don't have. What does your `NAMESPACE` look like? Where is `set()` defined? What steps did you take to build and install the package? Etc. FWIW, running your code outside the context of a package works just fine for me (with the exception of changing `set(...)` to `new("set", ...)`

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: This isn't a *full* solution, but may help you solve your problem and wouldn't fit as a comment.

So, the GitHub repo you linked to was pretty involved, and I couldn't get it working. So, what I did instead was start a fresh package with nothing in it, then add your code to a single R file `R/set.R`.

When I tried documenting and building, it didn't like this because there wasn't a title for `set-methods`. I also noticed there wasn't an `@export` tag. So, I added those two things for the full file to include:

```
#' @title The Set class
#' @slot ris A 2-column character dataframe
#' @slot tfs A character vector of TF names
#' @import dplyr
#' @export
setClass(
    "set",
    slots = list(
        ris = "data.frame",
        tfs = "character"
    )
)
#' @title Constructor function of a set object.
#' @description Constructor function of a set object.
#' @param ris A 2-column character dataframe of TF-gene interactions.
#' @param tfs A character vector of TF names.
#' @return A `set` object.
#' @export
set <-  function(ris, tfs) {
    new("set", ris = ris, tfs = tfs)
}

#' @title Placeholder title.
#' @name get_tfs
#' @aliases get_tf,set-method
#' @param x A `set` object
#' @docType methods
#' @rdname set-methods
#' @return A character vector
#' @export
setGeneric("get_tfs",
           valueClass = "character",
           function(x){
               standardGeneric("get_tfs")
           }
)
setMethod(
    "get_tfs",
    signature(x = "set"),
    function(x) {
        x@tfs
    }
)
```

After that, I documented and built, and it worked how I think you expect it to work:

```
library(set)
ris <- data.frame(1)
tfs <- "a"
test <- set(ris, tfs)
is(test)
# [1] "set"
get_tfs(test)
# [1] "a"
```

So, it seems to me that you probably have a pretty involved issue that might take quite a bit of debugging considering you have a lot of code in that repository, and (to my mind) some unconventional ways of doing things in that repository (e.g. what in the world is `NetworkEval/main.R`?).

I hope this demonstration of a minimal working example with your own code helps you come to a full solution.

Comment: Hi, after a bit of a struggle, I seem to have found the origin of the problem: in my library I defined another class of objects, and that other class has a method of the same name "get_tfs", when I comment it the issue disappears. So for now I renamed one of the methods. However I feel like R should be able to apply either method depending on the class of the input? Maybe I am still missing out on a few conventions.